# Regex Extract with two different delimiters

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Working in Google Data Studio and having trouble extracting a string between two different delimiters

For example if I have the following line item:

```
Company_Clothes_Shirt:Red_Online_US
```

I would like to extract just `Red`

I’ve tried
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Dimension,'^(?:[^\\_]*\\_){2}([^\\:]*\\:){1}')` but it just gives me `Shirt:`

Tried several other iterations but have only been able to extract the first part (`Shirt`), rather than the second (`Red`).

Would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract based on the whole string, you can just extract the value between the two delimiters:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(Dimension,':([^_]+)_')
```

For an input value of `Company_Clothes_Shirt:Red_Online_US`, this will give `Red`.

Note that neither `_` or `:` are special characters for regex, so they don't need to be escaped.